# How to start console and read output from there in windows services or emulate this?

Tags: java, c#, process, windows-services, console-application

I have some jar files that use in my c# console application (start them via `System.Diagnostics.Process`) and read console output form my purpouse.

Now I need change this console app to windows service.

```
m_process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "java.exe",
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        LoadUserProfile = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    }
};

m_process.Start();
m_process.BeginOutputReadLine();
m_process.BeginErrorReadLine();
m_process.WaitForExit();
m_process.Close();
m_process.Dispose();

m_process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataReceived;
m_process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataReceived;
```

jar files provide me information for my needs via console output. It works in console app but service doesn't rise any console so I can't read output.

I understand that I can't start a console in windows service. But I am looking for any other way to start my jar files and read output from them.

Comment: Try attaching the event handlers before the process ends. Preferably before you start the process so you don't miss any output.

Comment: @mikez the problem is that I don't have any output window at all in windows service.

Comment: Way is to read the input from file that can be XML or text file.  Because what you are asking is not possible in services as console will not be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A windows service is a background job. It doesn't have a console.

Remember that the service runs as soon as windows boots. Meaning that it runs even before the user logs in. There isn't even a user to show the console to, even if you magically were able to open a console.

On servers, it's common for there not to be a monitor connected at all. Who would see your output?

**Solution**

If you want to generate output from your background program, write it to a log file.

Comment: Problem is third party jar files generate output and I couldn't change this, because I don't have sources of this files.

Comment: How are you running the Java code as a windows service? Usually, the "service runner" can redirect console output to a log file.

Comment: arguments contains path to number of jar files and them are started. Do you recommend me to use SetOut (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) or any other way?

Comment: No, `SetOut` changes the output of your C# code. You're already redirecting the output of the Java process by setting `RedirectStandardOutput = true` and calling `BeginOutputReadLine()`, but you must do `OutputDataReceived +=` before calling `Start()`. That way, your event handler `ProcessOutputDataReceived` can read that output stream and write the text to a log file. At least according the example I just saw: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx